# Composite design pattern in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, composite

In java I can implement the [composite design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) as follows:

```
interface Component{
    void operation();

}

class Composite implements Component{
    @override
    public void operation(){
       for(Child child in children){
           child.operation();
       }
    }        

    public void add(Component child){//implementation}
    public void remove(Component child){//implementation}
    public void getChild(int index);
 }

 class Leaf implements Component{
      @override
      public void operation(){
         //implementation
      }
 }
```

How can I write it in scala? In particular I am having trouble understanding how to write an interface and implement it?

Comment: http://scala.sygneca.com/patterns/gofcomposite

Comment: Thanks! Wow,  that looks like alien speak to me :( I am not sure what "Activity" is...

Comment: Just to warn, that example on the sygneca wiki is looking *seriously* dated by current standards.  We can write much cleaner Scala nowadays :)

Comment: You can now ignore that last comment, I updated the wiki :)

Comment: @Kevin: the link is down. Is there another link? thanks

Comment: @ib84: all sygneca content has been migrated to the EPFL scala wiki.  Much of it is still in the process of being tidied up: https://wiki.scala-lang.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scala, a Trait without any concrete methods is just an interface.  So a direct translation would be:

```
trait Component { def operation(): Unit }

class Composite extends Component {
  def operation() = children foreach { _.operation() }
  def add(child: Component) = ...
  def remove(child: Component) = ...
  def getChild(index: Int) = ...
}

class Leaf extends Component {
  def operation() = ...
}
```

Though if you want more idiomatic Scala, I'd recommend something like this as a definition for `Composite`:

```
class Composite extends Component {
  def operation() = children foreach { _.operation() }
  def +=(child: Component) = ...
  def -=(child: Component) = ...
  def apply(index: Int) = ...
}
```

To be used as:

```
val comp = new Composite
comp += child1
comp += child2
comp -= child1
val firstChild = comp(0)
```

If you want to take this to a logical conclusion, I'd advocate building the whole composite structure as an immutable Directed Acyclic Graph (though I appreciate that this often isn't possible):

```
case class Composite(children: Component*) extends Component {
  def operation() = children foreach { _.operation() }
}

val comp = Composite(child1, Composite(child2, child3), child4)
```

Comment: @drozzy `+=` and `-=` are just nicer names for `add` and `remove`. `apply` is an alternative to `getChild` that allows the composite to be used as though it were a function or array.  I added an example to illustrate this.

Comment: Wow, I like the apply operator. Thanks. What does Component* (with a star) mean? Array?

Comment: @drozzy - `Component*` means it's a variable argument list, not a single argument.  If you have a sequence that you want to pass in, you'd pass it as `seq: _*`; otherwise, you'd just do `Composite(firstchild, secondchild /*, etc.*/)`

Comment: How come the operation method is not **def operation():Unit** as in Landei's answer?

Comment: @drozzy - It **is** `operation(): Unit`, but in my case I've simply allowed the compiler to infer the return type instead of stating it explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

trait Component{
    def operation():Unit
}

class Composite extends Component{

    val children = new ListBuffer[Component]()

    def operation():Unit = children.foreach {_.operation() }

    def add(child: Component):Unit = children += child
    def remove(child: Component):Unit = children -= child
    def getChild(index:Int) = children(index)
 }:

 class Leaf extends Component {
      def operation():Unit = println("leaf") 
 }
```

This is a very direct translation. Often an immutable solution is preferred in Scala. Another difference is, that you often use pattern matching instead of inheritance. E.g. you could rewrite the example by removing `operation()` from `Component` and `Leaf` and writing instead

```
trait Component{
    def operation():Unit = this match {
      case c:Composite => c.children.foreach(_.operation())
      case leaf:Leaf => println("leaf")  
    }
}
```

Comment: but were did add and remove of children go?

Comment: @drozzy - add and remove of children are still in `Composite`, that method was added to `Component`

Comment: It's too bad there is no @override notation, as it is not clear which methods are defined in which class...

Comment: `override` is a keyword in Scala and is compulsory whenever overriding a concrete method from some superclass. You may, however, see an abstract method that's *declared* in a superclass - and you don't need `override` for simply implementing inherited abstract methods. What exactly seemed unclear to you?

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner immutable way would be:

```
trait Component {
  def operation()
  def +(other: Component): Component = new Composite(this, other)
}

class Leaf(name: String) extends Component {
  override def operation(): Unit = println(name)
}

class Composite(children: Component*) extends Component {
  override def operation(): Unit = children foreach { _.operation() }
}

val c = new Leaf("Tom") + new Leaf("Tim")
c.operation() // Tom Tim
```

Answer (score 0):

Functionality presented in Java as an interface can be coded in Scala as a trait

```
trait Component{
    def operation():Unit
}

class Composite extends Component{
    @override
    def operation(){
       for(child<-children)
         child.operation()
    }        

    def add(child:Component){//implementation}
    def remove(child:Component){//implementation}
    def getChild(index:Int){//implementation}
 }

 class Leaf extends Component{
      def operation(){
         //implementation
      }
 }
```

It's worth saying that traits are more powerful than Java interfaces, and can include implementation as well as interface specifications.

Comment: You left the `@override` attribute in there :)